# When two like charges are placed at a large distance from each other, do they attract each other?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law, distance

So my friend and I were arguing about this. He insists that if two like charges are placed at a large distance from each other, they attract each other. I find this nonsense. This clearly violates Coulomb's law. He also says the force of interaction is not proportional to $\frac {1} {r^2}$

Assume electromagnetic induction won't come in play here. It won't do much anyway, given the large distance. And though I'm not sure, he was probably talking about point charges.

Is he actually right?

Comment: Did he give a reason?

Comment: Nope. He just said that his professor told him.

Comment: Was the professor talking of QCD, color charges?  They always attract even different colors. http://www.phy.duke.edu/~kolena/modern/hansen.html

Comment: @anna no, I'd highly doubt that.  It was a classical physics class. Plus, we are just starting with electrostatics right now so it probably shouldn't be something this advanced. I don't even know what a hadron exactly is. I guess there is some explanation (or misconception) in classical terms.

Comment: He may just meant that they were interacting, not attracting

Answer (score 1):

In vacuum, any two point charges bearing electric charge of the same sign will solely interact, if they are pinned at a particular distance, via the Coulomb force that is in $\sim \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$ as you say so that they will always repel no matter the distance.

Now, if you take in vacuum any two charged pieces of the same material (even at the nanoscale) bearing net charges of the same sign, then they will interact via a combination of the Coulomb interaction (ultra dominant at most length scales) and the so-called van der Waals interaction that is always attractive for objects made of the same material and fundamentally due to charge fluctuations in the material.

I don't know if this is what your friend was referring to but that is the only sense I can give to your friend's claim, as far as I am aware of.

Comment: But isn't the magnitude of wan der Waals force a lot less than the magnitude of electrostatic force. This would mean a net attractive force, right?

Comment: yes the magnitude of the van der Waals force is normally much smaller than that of the Coulomb force. So I would say that the repulsive Coulomb force always wins despite the existence of vdW. However, it does also mean that the actual full force profile is not exactly Coulomb but Coulomb + vdW.